# How to configure project-defaults.yml with jmsra?

Tags: java, jms, wildfly-swarm

My Java project runs with Wildfly Swarm. I have to update the `project-defaults.yml` to use the jmsra library (JMS MQ), but I was not able to find out how to add the jmsra configuration for the `project-defaults.yml`.

I have seen many posts that deals with ActiveMQ, but I cannot use it.

Do you have any tips or examples to configure Wildfly Swarm with jmsra.rar?

Comment: Which exact JMS resource adapter library are you trying to use? Just saying `jmsra` or `jmsra.rar` is too vague. There are several JMS JCA resource adapters available.

Comment: Exactly what Justin asks. Here are 3 examples of using different resource adapters that might be useful for you: https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/ejb-mdb-activemq https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/ejb-mdb-amqp https://github.com/rhoar-qe/thorntail-test-suite/tree/master/javaee/ejb-mdb-artemis

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answers. Actually, I try use jmsra.rar in my project-defaults.yml. I'm checking your links @Ladicek, I have seen many things that can be useful for me :) The artemys way looks like a similar way to configure my jmsra.rar